# How to do pivotal in Hive without using custom UDF or left joins ?

Tags: hadoop, hive, pivot-table, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

**Sample input:**

```
PARTY      |TYPE | TIMESTAMP
-------------------------------------
135761103  |AA   |2017-04-24 11:18:46.233  
135761103  |BB   |2017-04-24 11:19:18.436
```

**Desired output:**

```
PARTY |AA_TIMESTAMP|BB_TIMESTAMP   
--------------------------------
135761103  |2017-04-24 11:18:46.233 |2017-04-24 11:19:18.436
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried, it will be useful to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How rotate sql result entries into columns (pivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769865/how-rotate-sql-result-entries-into-columns-pivot)

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772741/2700344

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `CASE` & `GROUP BY` combination. Something like:

```
SELECT
    PARTY,
    max(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'AA' THEN TIMESTAMP END) AS AA_TIMESTAMP,
    max(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'BB' THEN TIMESTAMP END) AS BB_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
    MY_TAB
GROUP BY
    PARTY
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, Updated the answer.